# What is the better way to select from table with two condition from the same column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I've been trying to select into database with three condition and the two are from the same column.

I have a flowlayoutpanel with usercontrol and I can't seem to view all data with different value from the same column.

I have tried

```
SELECT borrowID, studentID, bookTitle, dateBorrowed, dueDate, status  FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE status = 'Not Returned' AND status = 'Overdue' AND studentNum = @studentNum
```

but sadly doesn't work.

I have also tried

```
    public void BooksOnHand()
    {
        ucBooksOnHand uc = new ucBooksOnHand(this);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        cn.Open();
        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT borrowID, studentID, bookTitle, dateBorrowed, dueDate, status  FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE status = 'Not Returned' AND studentNum = @studentNum", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentNum", frmissue.lblStudNo.Text);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //ucBooksOnHand uc = new ucBooksOnHand(this);
            uc.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            uc.lblBorrowID.Text = dr["borrowID"].ToString();
            uc.lblStudentID.Text = dr["studentID"].ToString();
            uc.lblBookName.Text = dr["bookTitle"].ToString();
            uc.lblDateBorrowed.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateBorrowed"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            uc.lblDueDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            uc.lblStatus.Text = dr["status"].ToString();
            uc.dtDueDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }

    public void BooksOverdue()
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT borrowID, bookTitle, studentID, dateBorrowed, dueDate, status  FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE status = 'Overdue' AND studentNum = @studentNum", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentNum", frmissue.lblStudNo.Text);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ucBooksOnHand uc = new ucBooksOnHand(this);
            uc.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            uc.lblBorrowID.Text = dr["borrowID"].ToString();
            uc.lblStudentID.Text = dr["studentID"].ToString();
            uc.lblBookName.Text = dr["bookTitle"].ToString();
            uc.lblDateBorrowed.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateBorrowed"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            uc.lblDueDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            uc.lblStatus.Text = dr["status"].ToString();
            uc.dtDueDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

The above code worked for me but I am looking for a better and simple solution for my problem.

Here are some data from the table

```
borrowID    studentID   bookID  studentNum      bookTitle   dateBorrowed  dueDate    returnedDate   status
10          1           1       2020-01-0001    Worthless   2020-03-30   2020-04-06  Mar 30 2020    Returned
11          1           1       2020-01-0001    Worthless   2020-03-23   2020-03-27  Mar 30 2020    Returned
12          1           2       2020-01-0001    Heartless   2020-03-30   2020-04-06                 Not Returned
13          1           1       2020-01-0001    Worthless   2020-03-15   2020-03-28                 Overdue
```

And I want to show all the books in possession of a student that is still not returned and is overdue.

Sample output that I want:

```
Books In Possesion:

Book Name   Status
----------|-------------
Heartless | Not Returned
Worthless | Overdue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an `AND` on the same column with two different values.  You need to use an `OR` for these in brackets like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (status = 'Not Returned' OR status = 'Overdue') AND studentNum = @studentNum
```

Another maybe better method is to use the IN operator.  Certainly better if you have more than two items to check

```
SELECT ... WHERE status IN('Not Returned', 'Overdue') AND studentNum = @studentNum
```

Comment: It doesn't show both the `'Not Returned'` and `'Overdue'` items at the same time though, only one of the two is showing

Comment: @kemchan Edit your question to include sample data & expected results as _formatted text_ please not images.

Comment: @kemchan please check the data in your DB table.  Or, as suggested, post your sample data.  Check out the DB fiddle:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkaoe7vcjVHk9WAo7L5H1J/1

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith when i execute the query in the database, the `IN` is working but when I try to run it on c#, it is only showing one of the items

Comment: Maybe the problem is in my frontend, thank you so much for the answer